# How to show a certain place only in Google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am a beginner in android just started last 2 days. I was suddenly interested of it because i attended a short seminar about android. I am currently developing for self learning and aiming for an app that is supported by Jellybean 4.1 above which shows a map. I already know that about API and etc. The map displays now but what i want to aim is to display only a certain location when i open a map. For example, i will open the app (FOR SOUTH KOREA only) and the GPS is enabled automatically and it will determine that i am currently in SEOUL. The map will not show other countries but set to south korea only and will zoom to Seoul City only. Here is the code i have but now im slightly disappointed because i received too many errors which i dont understand.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng seoul = new LatLng(8.2280, 124.2452);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(seoul).title("Marker in seoul"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seoul));
        mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(8.2280,124.2452) , 14.0f) );
    }
}
```

I did the answer below and got a couple more errors:

```
3:54:02 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
3:56:41 PM Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 2m 38s 461ms
3:56:52 PM Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
3:58:54 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
3:58:57 PM Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 2s 642ms
3:58:57 PM Gradle sync started
3:58:57 PM Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
3:59:00 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find method dexOptions() for arguments [build_6ssnj5v7kqqke9vdyrxx62l1w$_run_closure3@35c11173] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
4:02:08 PM Executing tasks: [assemble]
4:03:49 PM Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 1m 40s 546ms
4:03:49 PM Gradle sync started
4:03:49 PM Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
4:04:17 PM Gradle sync completed



  Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:7 errors; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: what are the error? can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()

    .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View

    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom

    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east

    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees

    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help :

```
if (seoul!=null) {

        mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        mMarkerOptions.position(seoul);
        mMarkerOptions.title(completeAddress);
        mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions).showInfoWindow();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(seoul));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(seoul, 14.0f));
    }
```